# Should I always accept an answer on The Workplace?

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer

I asked a question a couple of days ago, and thankfully I got great positive feedback for the situation I'm currently in. The issue or more like the dilemma is that I really can't accept just one answer. I like several of them and I haven't had enough feedback (on my end) to determine which one was the correct answer.

Must questions on **The Workplace** have an accepted answer? What do I do if a combination of 2 or more answers solved my problem? How will I know then which one should be accepted?

Comment: "Does The Workplace must have an accepted answer?" - no. Lots of questions clearly have no accepted answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll start by referring you to the [SE FAQ on accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/260884). This should help explain how things work across all Stack Exchange sites, but I'll answer your questions specifically.

Accepting an answer is never required, but we do usually encourage it. An accepted answer indicates to everyone that the given advice was useful and helped you in your situation. Because the Workplace focuses mainly on more subjective questions that don't have clearly correct or incorrect answers, there are often multiple answers with different approaches which could all be useful. And sometimes the best answer for you is a combination of tactics from multiple answers.

Unfortunately there is no way to mark multiple answers as correct on any SE site. This does make sense, as having multiple conflicting answers marked as correct would add a lot of confusion and be not at all useful to future readers. We do still encourage you to pick the answer that was the most useful to you and accept it. Definitely still use your votes to promote the other answers you liked, and maybe even edit your question to specifically say "I accepted Jack's answer, but make sure to read Jill's answer which was also very useful!" If you want to wait a little longer to get more feedback on your end, that's perfectly fine. We always like to see edits updating us on the situation and explaining which advice ultimately turned out to be be useful or not.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure if rules were different or equal between SE sites, I appreciate the link.

Comment: Aside from accepting an answer, I'd encourage people to provide an update on how the situation resolved itself as an edit to their question. A few short lines on what you decided to do and how everything worked out can be very valuable and provide a sense of closure that questions often lack, particularly on the Workplace.

Comment: All I would add is to give it a day or so before accepting. You may may get answers with a new perspective that might change your mind from your initial decision.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not have to, since answers may collude to give your case a perfect solution or other approaches may still be useful, but you just decided not to use them. But what is of benefit to other users is for you to explain in detail the approach you took and why, and possibly what results where gotten. For deeper questions, this can take up to a week or even more.

**Additionally**

I think for that particular issue, the Stack team must try to consider adding a resolution field (much like a dedicated field below question) where the approach taken is well documented.

Comment: Great idea! I love it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I think it's good to mark an answer as accepted. However, there have been times when I wasn't satisfied with any answers and didn't accept an answer. Also there have been questions which turn out to be controversial and two (or more) strongly defended, but opposing positions are advocated in the answers; in such cases, I have left all answers as "unaccepted" out of respect for people with other opinions, although I do upvote answers that share my opinion.