# Can I use meta to ask which answer I should accept?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic-definition, meta

I have a question where I'm not sure which answer to accept.
 (*[How do I list an internship on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/94549/68427)*)

Initially when the question was asked, there were only two answers to chose from, which meant I didn't have many options for an accepted answer. Later my question [was bountied](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/94549/revisions), which led to me having seven valid answers to choose from. (Which, to be fair, is not a bad problem to have)

**Is it acceptable to ask on meta if I'm unsure which answer I should accept on a question?**

Comment: I strongly doubt it. You're supposed to accept the answer that *you* found most useful. That's it. If you want to go with popular opinion you accept the answer with the most upvotes. If you can't choose you don't accept any. This seems more of a question for [chat] than meta.

Comment: There's another meta question that isn't quite a duplicate, but you'd probably find quite useful: [Should I always accept an answer on The Workplace?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3761/should-i-always-accept-an-answer-on-the-workplace)

Comment: "Is it acceptable to ask on meta if I'm unsure which answer I should accept on a question?" - you can ask anything you want. But it's really your choice, so asking others is rather silly. It's not all that important which one you choose - just make a choice and pick the one you like the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), meta is the place to discuss how the site works, and policies that affect the site as a whole. Meta is not the right place to get feedback on personal decisions.

While we do use meta to discuss specific questions, in particular, how to improve questions to reopen them, this still contributes to improving the site as a whole.

With a bit of rules lawyering, we could prove that asking help to choose an "accepted answer" also contributes to the site, but in my opinion, that goes too far beyond the scope of meta.

As other users have pointed out, the voting mechanism already allows the community to give feedback on the answers, so asking them to vote *again* on those answers here is redundant. Besides, people visit meta less frequently than the main site.

Comment: ooooo rules lawyering.  I've heard it put another way, but I doubt I could post what we call it

Answer (score 4):

You should decide for yourself, or not.

the "best answer" only grants fifteen points, so nobody is going to be badly hurt by **NOT** getting the best answer.  You're not under an obligation.

By the same token, you're not going to unfairly grant anyone huge advantage by picking them.

But the choice is really yours alone to make.

You could say that the community has itself, already chipped in by voting, and an upvote is worth 10 rep points, so the community has already had their fair share in rewarding the person.

IF you're not sure, go with whoever has the most up votes.