# Can I combine different answers into one and how?

Tags: discussion, answers

Recently I asked a question that got a lot of advice and a few part-answers. Is there any way to combine the part answers into one answer?

My question is here:
[Is there any risk in sharing info about technologies and products we use with a supplier?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/130250/is-there-any-risk-in-sharing-info-about-technologies-and-products-we-use-with-a/130433#130433)

Answers vary from advice like "Just write an email saying 'bla bla', dont feel bad" to actual answers like (my paraphrasing):

1. The info you provide could be [used against your company in ways you
   cannot predict.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/130265/32591)
2. If you provide constructive criticism [your company could benefit.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/130286/32591)
3. You can [probably share](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/130252/32591) what is already irrevocably available online

**EDIT**: If I can take the answer to [this question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3761/should-i-always-accept-an-answer-on-the-workplace) to mean "No, **and** to write your own answer as a combination from other answers given by other people will be seriously frowned upon" - then my question has been answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I always accept an answer on The Workplace?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3761/should-i-always-accept-an-answer-on-the-workplace)

Comment: Question, why do you want to combine those answers into one? Just to be able to accept one? They are already posted on your Q, so anybody can use those suggestions and take benefit from all of them.

Comment: Another way of putting it may be, do you seek to obtain/construct a canonical answer for your post?

Comment: An interesting question, perhaps this was already discussed on the main meta? I wonder if there's a site-wide best practice on creating canonical answers based on multiple distinct ones. But I expect it will come down to how much effort you put into the consolidated answer.

Comment: @DarkCygnus I think a good anwer takes all aspects discussed in the now available separate answers into account.